# How many times a particular App has been downloaded -- where is this info?

Tags: iphone, ipad

Re: Apps in the Apple Store (iPhone &iPad) --

I've never seen a source that lists how many times a certain App has been downloaded / paid for.  Is there one?

I'm deciding what to do for my next App and would like to check around and see how some individual Apps are selling that are in my area.  To see if there's a market for whatever I'm going to do.

I believe Apple used to list how many times an individual App had been downloaded.  But it's not there now.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't released any app on the App Store yet? Sales stats are private to each developer, you won't find the numbers anywhere. That said, some devs sometimes share figures in forums or blogs.

Answer (score 2):

Log onto your developer account and go to iTunes connect.  Information about all of you apps is there with download reports, crash logs, etc.